# A list of low-dimensional associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with non-trivial centers

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, associative-algebras

I am looking for a list of (examples of) low(est)-dimensional non-commutative associative unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebras $A$ with **non-trivial centers** $Z(A)$ (hence non-semisimple). For our purposes $Z(A)$ is trivial iff it is a product of copies of $\mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra itself.

Does anyone know of such a list? Most of google's returns is about CSAs or semisimple Lie algebras and such, which is kinda the opposite of what I am looking for.

There are many examples from group rings, but I am hoping for something smaller than, say, $\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)[S_3]$.